# optimistic concurrency exception was handled by the user code

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, objectstatemanager

I'm using MVC4 with Entity Framework 4.1.

Initially we have created an Ado.net entity model from database. In the .edmx file, some of the tables that are in the database are not visible as they dont posses the primary key on particular table.

As our project is moving forward, we need to update to one of the log tables which dont have a primary key field.

So, we modified our .edmx file instead of modifying in the database. our client asked us not to modify the database fields. we have modified the .edmx and created a pk on one of the exisiting field in the table(say `tbl_log` table).

we are trying to update the tbl_log. But it gives an error message as `Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.`

I've seen much of questions in stack overflow and also googled a bit, but could not find any solution.

Even i've tried refreshing the ObjectStateManager entries but it still points to the same error.

Here is my code

```
    tbl_log log = new tbl_log();

                    Entity.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(System.Data.EntityState.Modified);

    log.LoginId = strLoginId;
    log.Password = strPassword;
    log.IPAddress = strIpAddress;
    log.Date_Time = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString());
    log.sessionId = new Guid(strSessionId);

    Entity.AddTotbl_log(log);

Entity.SaveChanges();// optimistic concurrency error
```

Please help

Thanks,

Karthik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model must represent the database schema. If you add a PK to the model it should exist in the database as well, otherwise you will get errors. It's generally bad practice to not have a PK on any table, even if the table is an audit log table.

What the exception is telling you is that the object tracker cannot determine if the state of the object has changed since the last call to the database. This is because the PK you have set is still 0 even after the framework has sent the insert/update query.

Unfortunately there is no good way to work around this. I would suggest (as I think Microsoft does) to add a primary key column to every table in your database.

**EDIT - From comments**

As the PK is used to track the object, if you have set the PK to have a StoreGenerationPattern of Identity in your model it will be expecting the value to change. When it doesn't change then it will throw the error your are seeing. Try changing the StoreGenerationPattern to None as then EF won't be expecting your faux-PK to change

Comment: I've added PK for the column that is already existing in the database. But there is no PK defined for that column in database.

Comment: The PK is used to track the object, so if you have set the PK to have a `StoreGenerationPattern` of `Identity` in your model it will be expecting the value to be changed. When it doesn't change then it will throw the error your are seeing. Try changing it to `None` as then EF won't be expecting your faux-PK to change.

Comment: +1 Thank you Ryan Amies, it worked when `StoreGenerationPattern` is set to `None` in the model

Comment: No problem, if this answer was correct, consider marking it as correct

Comment: I've this error when executed twice: `The ObjectContext might be in an inconsistent state. Inner exception message: AcceptChanges cannot continue because the object's key values conflict with another object in the ObjectStateManager. Make sure that the key values are unique before calling AcceptChanges.`. I think this is because the primary key value is always zero. What should i do to ignore this

Comment: This is of course related to the other issue, because EF cannot keep track of what state the entity is. Try tacking a look at the article below, but really I think you need to look at your database model and have a think as you're just working up hill here. http://pratapreddypilaka.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/entity-framework-adding-datatable-with.html